# Regarding string stream delimeters missing the last line in text file

Tags: c++, stringstream

As I read data from a textfile in the following fashion "[1,2,3,4,5] [1,2,3,4,5]"
I'm getting a result of 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 when using commas as a delimiter in the following code.

```
while (getline (ss, data, ','))
    {
        stringstream fs (data);
        int d = 0;
        fs >> d;
        orderVector.push_back(d);
    }
```

My guess is that this is due to the 5 and the 1 not having a comma between but I'm not sure what to do to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are the data on separate lines? Or is all the input on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to bother doing any validation (no indication that you feel that necessary in your old code), then you could do this:

```
while (true)
{
    int d;
    if (ss >> d)
        orderVector.push_back(d);
    else
    {
        if (ss.eof()) break;
        ss.clear();
        ss.ignore();
    }
}
```